# How to change the orientation of specific ViewController in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation

I want to change the orientation of specific ViewController in Xcode.

I make a,b,cViewController and change the orientation only cViewController to LandscapeRight. (a and b's orientation are Portrait)

But if I change the orientation on cViewController and move ViewController from c to b, b's orientation is also changed to LandscapeRight.
(screen transition is push)

code:

**a and bViewController's DidLoad**

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; 
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

**cViewController's DidLoad**

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; 
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

How can I change the orientation only cViewController?

Comment: change this from `DidLoad` to `DidAppear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step-1**

create the one bool property in your appdelegate like , this

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

and call the function

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if(self.restrictRotation)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape ;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**step-2**

and import the appdelegate `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in C VC

on your C VC View Will appear, call like

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
// for rotate the VC to Landscape
[self restrictRotationwithNew:YES];
}

(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   // rotate the VC to Portait
  [self restrictRotationwithNew:NO];

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


-(void) restrictRotationwithNew:(BOOL) restriction
{
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;

}
```

**Choice 2**

on your C VC check the Orientation using the delegate function of `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];



 - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{


     [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];


}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation    {

UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

switch (deviceOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

        NSLog(@"orientationPortrait");
       ;

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

        NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown");
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

        NSLog(@"OrientationLandscapeLeft");



        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:

        NSLog(@"OrientationLandscapeRight");

        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```